# How to increase Width of series groups on a range chart MS Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, bar-chart, gantt-chart

I have a report with a range chart that is supposed to be used as Gant chart.
Tools:

> MS SQL Server 2014 + Reporting Services + VS2013 BI

At **Design** area chart looks like:

[image: Design view]

But at **Preview** it's become like that:

[image: Preview]

All series bars became very thin, why? How to avoid? There is plenty of space around. I used `CustomAttributes` for series as `PointWidth=0,5;` but it made changes only at **Design** view. When switch to **Preview** all bars become very thin again.

**UPD:**
Rreplaced names (vertical Axis) with theirs IDs. BTW, what settings are responsible for the distance between values of Vertical Axis?:

[image]

If I reduce time frame to one operation only, it becomes like below. Also, does anyone know why there is so huge empty area between 39-40?:
[image]

Comment: The names of your values (left) are pretty big. They are taking up a lot of the space on your report. Can you force them to word-wrap or use abbreviations?

Comment: Yes, just replaced the with theirs ID (that is 2 digit numbers). It didn't help anyhow. Is there any other ideas? What does force the lines/bars to become thin?

Comment: You might be using a setting that makes the graph an exact height. Changing the graph height, based on the number of tasks, would solve what you are showing.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I've tried dynamical height with script based on tasks quantity. Overall height is changing but all inside scale up/down with those empty areas as well.

Comment: Having more tasks in your data will cause the bars to be thinner. Example: Your first picture shows that only had 2 tasks. Your second picture shows 19 tasks and thinner bars. In your fourth picture, did you only have 1 task in your resultset (data) or several tasks, but only one with values showing on the graph?

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I changed the query so to get only one action with only one task and duration. Yes, it looks better...anyway with unusable space below and above...but I need a chart with many tasks and this auto scale makes all bad. Thanks for help.